# Laravel + Vuejs have trouble with async problem

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a async problem with my Vuejs/Laravel App.

If a user is connected i have in vuex : my state user and a state token. I set this token in the localStorage and with that i can relogin him if my user F5 (refresh page).

There is my store (namespaced:auth) :

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        token: null,
        user: null
    },
    getters: {
        authenticated(state){
            return state.token && state.user;
        },
        user(state){
            return state.user;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_TOKEN(state, token){
            state.token = token;
        },
        SET_USER(state, data){
            state.user = data;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        async login({ dispatch }, credentials){
           let response = await axios.post(`/api/auth/connexion`, credentials);

           dispatch('attempt', response.data.token);
        }
        , 
        async attempt({ commit, state }, token) {
            if(token){
                commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
            }
            if (!state.token){
                return
            }
            try{
                let response = await axios.get(`/api/auth/me`);
                commit('SET_USER', response.data);
                console.log('Done')
            }
            catch(err){
                commit('SET_TOKEN', null);
                commit('SET_USER', null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app.js, i do that for relog my current user :

```
store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

And for finish on route in router :

```
{
    name: 'Login',
    path: '/',
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      console.log('Getter in router : ' + store.getters['auth/authenticated']);
      if (!store.getters['auth/authenticated']){
        next()
      }else {
        return next({
          name: 'Home'
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Where is the problem, if i call in a Home.vue my getter "authenticated" is work fine (true if user connect and false if not).

But in my router is take all time default value set in store (null). I know why is because if i reload my page for 0.5s the store state is null and after that the localStorage is learn and my user and token is created.

What i want (i think) is the router wait my actions attempt and after that he can do check.

I have follow a tutoriel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YGWP-mj6nQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF1jqLcNO_2jWJXj9RuSDvY&index=6

And i really don't know what i need to do for my router work fine =(

Thanks a lot if someone can explain me that !

Update :

If i do that is work :

```
{
    name: 'Login',
    path: '/',
    component: Login,
     beforeEnter:async (to, from, next) => {
      await store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token'));

      if (!store.getters['auth/authenticated']){
        next()
      }else {
        return next({
          name: 'Home'
        })
      }
    }
```

But i want to understand what i really need to do because that is not a clear way is really trash.

Update2:

Maybe i found the best solution if someone have other way i take it.

```
{
    name: 'Home',
    path: '/accueil',
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token')).then((response) => {
        if (!store.getters['auth/authenticated']){
          return next({
            name: 'Login'
          })
        }else {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to trace down where the issue lies. I suggest you download Vue devtools (browser plugin firefox/chrome) so you can take a look at the state while it's running.

Comment: Is indeed hard to track, the devtools will help for sure, what i noticed is that your store is not defined as a function/closure, but as a static object which can conflict if you re-import it in the store. Resulting in being null.

Furthermore be sure, you imported store inside your router. and you could check if the module is loaded at. all. (also vue devtools makes that easyer)

Comment: Is your store module a fixed moduled in the main entry point of your store, or are you loading it dynamically.. that might also cause these issues..

Comment: Yes i use devtools and i see the vuex state is null for 0.5s and is set after.
But now with the method store.dispatch set in my router directly is work fine.

I juste don't know if has a better way to do that.
Thanks for you'r reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer more clearly how easily wait the store !

Before in my app.js i have this :

```
store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Is set for normaly every reload do that but if i put a console.log in, i see the router is execute and after the action 'attempt' is execute.

So delete this line in app.js and you can add a .then() after !

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token')).then(() =>{
    if (store.getters['auth/authenticated']){
      next();
    }else {
      //something other
    }
  })
})
```

With that i have the same line code but i can say wait action "attempt" to my router.

I'm not sur is the best way obviously. But is work and i think is not a bad way !